# How to change font or color setting of code disabled by conditional compilation?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, editor, settings

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
#define ABC

#ifdef ABC
int foo = 1;
#else
int bar = 2;
#endif
```

I want to modify displaying of the text inside `else` part of conditional compilation.

I'm using dark scheme in VS2012. Current setting will drop all colors except constants, comments and keywords which will get bit darker. I would like to change it to either drop all colors completely or change everything to different color.

I would really love to have the part which is not complied crossed (or at least italic) but that does not seem to be possible in VS editor at all.

Answer (score 4):

Please excuse me for bringing up a 2 year old topic, but this could better help the community in finding fast answers.

Sigve had provided correct answer but the following is in addition to what he had said.

If you are still not able to change the color of the Display item (Excluded code in this case), go to

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ (e.g.) -> View. Choose 'True' (default is false) to disable inactive code opacity. When you go back to the font and colors, and change the color for 'Excluded Code', the color will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165337(v=vs.110).aspx

> 1. Select Options from the Tools menu, and in the Environment folder, select Fonts and Colors.
>      The Fonts and Colors, Environment, Options Dialog Box opens.
> 2. In Show settings for, select Text Editor.
> 3. Modify the Font and Size options to change the font face and size for all text elements in all editors.
> 4. Select the appropriate item in Display items, and then modify the Item foreground and Item background options.

The item you want in `Display items` is `excluded code`.

Comment: That was looking very promising. I've just tried it and it does not work :(

Comment: Had a look at some links on the page I posted. This page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh923906(v=vs.110).aspx mentions a theme editor: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05

Comment: See the answer from gwkit, which adds to this. The combination of the two settings works perfectly in VS2019.